# Como puedo mostrar una vista creada en sql en mvc c# .net framework razor

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

cree una vista en SQL y quiero mostrarla en mi vista de Razor, utilizo c# con mvc.

Este es el codigo con el que estaba probando llamar a mi vista, pero en el foreach el modelo me llega nulo y me marca error, es por eso que pregunto como se invoca o llama a una vista sql

```html
@model IEnumerable<BDModelos.VistaGlobal_Empleados>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IdEmpleado)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombres)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApellidoPaterno)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ApellidoMaterno)
        </th>
        
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdEmpleado)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombres)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApellidoPaterno)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApellidoMaterno)
            </td> 
            <td>
               
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Comment: Actualice mi pregunta para que veas como estoy intentando llamar

Comment: Y ese modelo llama a tu vista?

Comment: Asi es, ese VistaGlobal_Empleados es la vista que cree y ya esta mapeada en mi model, ahora lo que yo quiero es "pintar" esos datos

Comment: Este es el error que me da cuando intento mostrar esa vista: System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

Comment: Y como retornas la lista de tu modelo de empleados a la vista desde el controlador?